# How can I read a ViewBag value?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor, viewbag

I need to read a value of a viewbag with a controller, how can I do that?

### Controller

```
app.controller('ConseilManagOrga', function ($scope, $http) {
$http.get("../api/Form/GetForm?id=" + @ViewBag.id).success(function (response) {
    $scope.FormFund = response;
});
```

});

### ViewBag

```
  if (Name == "ConseilManagOrga")
        {
            ViewBag.Form = "FormChildren";
            ViewBag.Controller = "ConseilManagOrga";
            ViewBag.Image = "stone.jpg";
            ViewBag.id = 3;
        }
```

Comment: What on earth is a viewBag? Is this related with Angular in any way? If not, I'd suggest to add a tag that explains it

Comment: Asp.Net MVC Viewbags are resolved server side on your view before the view is served up.  Afaik this is not possible / wouldn't make sense anyway.  You could set a globala variable in your view to a Viewbag but seems like a poor design choice

Comment: @PWKad, I agree it is a poor design choice to assign to a global variable, but you can just as easily assign to a AngularJS scope variable. Do you mean consider the use of global variable a poor design choice, or the whole practice in general?

Comment: There is almost no reason to do what the asker is attempting to do since an Angular app inside ASP.NET MVC will only evaluate that property from the viewbag once on load

Answer (score 3):

The best way in my opinion to do this is to write a script tag and set the value of a JavaScript variable to the ViewBag value using Razor:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var MyVariableFromViewBag = '@ViewBag.id';
</script>
```

This will create a global variable name MyVariableFromViewBag. Of course, you should avoid using global javascript variables in production code. Modify the sample to assign to a safer variable.

Comment: This answer is incorrect - using var (variableName) will not create a variable in the global scope, you should remove var or better yet for brevity use window.MyVariableFromViewbag

Comment: @PWKad I bet that MyVariableFromViewBag from his example will be stored in window object automatically due to it is a global object.

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround is to use a hidden input field which takes the value of your Viewbag value:

```
<input type="hidden" id="myId" value="@ViewBag.id" />
```

Then in your javascript file you can access this value by id:

```
var myId = $("#myId").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using ng-init is also another way to do this.

```
ng-init="vm.environment = '@ViewBag.Environment'"
```